# How to know whether a Google user account exists?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I want to know if a specific account is registered with Google.
Is it possible with Python?

Comment: What type of account?

Comment: You have to check google API for that weather it is providing or not.

Answer (score 2):

There is one way that you can do it is using **Selenium** in **Python**.

**Step 1**: Go to page : [Google check existed accounts](https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/recoveryidentifier?flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin).

**Step 2**: Write script to check if your account is existed or not by asserting the returned result and your expected result (such as if your account is not existed Google will notice that: "**No account found with that email address**").

**Step 3**: Return your result for later purposes.